# Ask about React: function of class convention

Tags: reactjs, coding-style, conventions

When do I use an arrow function?

```
class App extends Component {
        onButtonClick = event => console.log(click!)
}
```

and, When do I use a function of the class?

```
class App extends Component {
        onButtonClick() {console.log(click!)}
}
```

Comment: If you are using the function as an event handler, `onButtonClick()` would *not* have the desired `this` value without binding it to `this` in the constructor or in the render method. I think [this part of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) is a great read on the subject.

Comment: Thank your recommendation, But I want to know about the convention. When do I use an arrow function and a function of the class?

Comment: Please read the piece of the documentation I linked and it will make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's differentiate them,

Arrow functions do not require binding like normal functions.
They have a cleaner syntax.
 
They are not the standard way of coding in Reactjs.
If only a single statement is part of arrow function that it returns, you can omit curly braces.

Then, coming to usage...
Arrow function can be used for in a event handler where a value should be passed to the function, like **onClick=dothis(arg)** 
To do this, you have to wrap the **dothis** function in another function like **onClick=()=>dothis(arg)**, otherwise your event handler won't work as required.

I recommend using normal functions because Arrow functions are not mentioned in the standard documentation of Reactjs.

"""I prefer sticking to the standards"""